# req.isAuthenticated() returns false after some time the server started

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session-cookies, passport.js

I have implemented the following function in node js routes.js.Before any requested is served first it is checked for isAuthenticated.

```
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
    if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
        console.log('Session Expiry '+req.session.cookie.expires);
        console.log('Authenticated');
        return next();
    }
    console.log('Not Authenticated');
    res.redirect('/');
}
```

But when I refresh or navigate to other page after some time after opening the page,it goes to index page instead of the current page.I found it was because req.isAuthenticated() evaluates to false after some time the page loaded.

Why does it become false?

Is it because of improper serializing

This is my serialize and deserilize methods,am I doing in correctly,

```
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    console.log('Serializing User');
    done(null, user.id);
});

// used to deserialize the user
passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
    console.log('Calling Deserlize');
    dbconn.user_findById(id, function (err, user) {//call to query DB
        console.log('Deserializing user from DB');
        done(err, user);
    });
});
```

Is it concerned with cookie or session. Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

When you create the cookie middleware in express you need to set a session timeout:

```
app.use(express.session({
   secret : 'your_cookie_secret',
   cookie:{
     maxAge : 360000 // one hour in millis
   }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply Jivings ,But I have already included the middleware for the session app.use(express.session({ secret: 'mysecret', cookie: { maxAge: 12 * 3600 * 1000 } }));                               as 12 hours

Comment: This is my serialize and deserilize methods,am I doing in correctly,                                           passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
        console.log('Serializing User');
        done(null, user.id);
    });
    
    // used to deserialize the user
    passport.deserializeUser(function (id, done) {
        console.log('Calling Deserlize');
        dbconn.user_findById(id, function (err, user) {//call to query DB
            console.log('Deserializing user from DB');
            done(err, user);
        });
    });

Answer (score 0):

Sorry

Actually I published my website in azure.Because of the fact that azure sites restart after idle timeout of 20 minutes,the authentication failed